# How to set amount of floats with Python Locale {:n} format

Tags: python, locale

I'm trying to manually set the floating points with the python locale format (for Brazilian format) with a Pandas data frame on a [Streamlit](https://streamlit.io/) app:

```py
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.UTF-8')

st.dataframe(df[['FATURAMENTO', 'VENDAS']].describe().style.format("{:2n}"), use_container_width=True)
# the output is the same as without the 2
```

[image: Imgur]

The output rounds the values by default, no caring for how many floating points it will have, or even if it'll have. But I want it to have the amount I set in the `format` parameter.

Comment: What is `st`? What is `st.dataframe`? What is `df`?

Comment: And what do you mean by "limit"? What output, exactly, do you want?

Comment: I guess he wants to "limit" the number of decimal points.

Comment: I added more info in the post now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only just came across the question. I haven't used streamlit. But given pandas, the short answer should be:

```py
st.dataframe(df[['FATURAMENTO', 'VENDAS']].describe().style.format(
    formatter=lambda x: f'{locale.format_string("%.2f", x, grouping=True)}'), use_container_width=True)
```

The `df.describe().style.format(formatter=lambda x: f'{locale.format_string("%.2f", x, grouping=True)}')` syntax works on my systems.

**Longer answer:**

I used `locale.format_string()` to format the number to a string based on current locale for LC_NUMERIC.
Handling decimal precision is via "%.2f", i.e. formatting floating point numbers to two decimal places.

Different libc implementations (and versions) can have differing locale data, which means results will differ in certain aspects across platforms. I don't have pt_BR.UTF8 locale on my macOS, so I will illustrate with de_DE.UTF-8.

On Linux:

```py
import locale
number = 12546.78
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "de_DE.UTF-8")
print(number)
# 12546.78
print(locale.format_string("%.2f", number, grouping=True))
# 12.546,78
```

The locale formatted number, using glibc, is 12.546,78

For macOS:

```py
import locale
number = 12546.78
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "de_DE.UTF-8")
print(number)
# 12546.78
print(locale.format_string("%.2f", number, grouping=True))
# 12546,78
```

The locale formatted number using BSD libc is 12546,78. On BSD and BSD derived systems, grouping separators are null for numbers (although currency formatting often includes grouping separators) in some locales.

If you want a cross-platform solution, I would be inclined to use icu4c and PyICU:

```py
import icu
loc = icu.Locale("pt_BR")
formatter = icu.LocalizedNumberFormatter(loc).precision(icu.Precision.minMaxFraction(2,2))
st.dataframe(df[['FATURAMENTO', 'VENDAS']].describe().style.format(
    formatter=lambda x: f'{f.formatDouble(x)}'), use_container_width=True)
```